# Want to understand matplotlib polar/radial plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using  [this dataset from data.world](https://data.world/keithhultman/trumps-tweets-project/workspace/file?filename=trump-tweets-raw.csv) to learn how to plot radial charts using matplotlib and I am not really sure how to calculate the radius and the angle of the plot.

If I plot the data as a scatter plot with time in the x-axis and year month in the Y-axis, I will get the following: (ignore the dates on the x axis they are indeed time).

[image]

Now, I want to covert that into a radial or polar plot, like this: ( i used another tool to do that), where the angular axis is time and the radial is year month.

[image]

My question is, how do I calculate r and theta to plot that using matplotlib? In the how I mean the logic to convert cartesian to polar, not the actual code. I am looking to understand how it works in general.

```
c = ax.scatter(theta, r)
```

I have seen a few examples online, but none explains the logic behind? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polar plotting in matplotlib can be challenging because of the coordinate conversion, as you mentioned, and more so when you add the date/time to the x/y axis like in your case. Here is a stab at it.

The first important step is to open the data and condition it. We can use the `pandas` library to open the csv with your data ([data.world](https://data.world/login?next=%2Fkeithhultman%2Ftrumps-tweets-project%2Fworkspace%2Ffile%3Ffilename%3Dtrump-tweets-raw.csv)) and extract the y-axis which will be the year/month/day data, and the x-axis which will be the hour/minute/second data.

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates



df_csv = pd.read_csv('data-tweets.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=['created'])
# For some reason, the data is not in utf-8 so it needs encoding ISO-8859-1
# By passing parse_date we make the values in the column 'created' as pandas datetimes
print(f'Available columns: {df_csv.columns.values}')

# Filter for 2016 as an example
df = df_csv[(df_csv['created'] >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00') & (df_csv['created'] <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00')]
# Reset index with the 2016 data
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Extract year/month/day to plot as y-axis
date = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d').to_numpy()
# Extract hour:minute:second to plot as x-axis
time = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').to_numpy()
```

We can plot the data we currently have in the cartesian x/y coordinates so we can have a sanity check later.

```
# Time and date are currently strings, we need them to be python datetime (dt) objects so matplotlib can understand
date_dt = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in date]
time_dt = [datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in time]

# Initiate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), layout='tight')
ax.plot(time_dt, date_dt, 'o')

# Format date/time for both x and y axes
x_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_fmt)
y_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_fmt)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

# Label axes
ax.set_xlabel('Time [HH:MM:SS]')
ax.set_ylabel('Date [Y/m/d]')
fig.suptitle('Tweet timeline')

plt.show()
```

[image: fig_tweets]

Okay now on to the polar part. For polar coordinates you need `r`, radial coordinate, and `theta`, an angle. For more info, you can check
[Wikipedia's Polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) info, but the gist of it is that `r = square root of (x squared + y squared)`, and `theta = angle or fraction in radians` (i.e. to obtain radians you multiply by 2 * Pi). Roughly speaking, in this case you can think of `theta` as the x-axis, aka the time in hours, and `r` as the y-axis, aka the dates.

We have two issues to address before we calculate `r` and `theta`:

1. Before we can even begin to think about summing or squaring our x and y values, we need them to be actual numbers. x and y are currently `datetime` objects, which works for plotting with matplotlib (as before) but not for doing any math heavy operations with them. The key will be to convert the x/y datetime values into timestamps.
2. The key to converting from cartesian x/y to polar is that everything has to have the same units when time is involved. We currently don't have that, x is in dates, and y is in time.

Let's start with issue #1. Converting the y-axis to timestamps is easy enough using `date2num` from `matplotlib.dates` (you can use other methods to obtain the timestamp but using `date2num` and converting them into matplotlib timestamps will be incredibly useful later when we need to format the axes):

```
# We need date and time to be timestamps (i.e. a number, not a datetime object) so we can operate with them
# Chose directly to do matplotlib timestamps as we can later format the axes like we did before
date_timestamp = mdates.date2num(date_dt)
```

However, the x-axis is a bit more tricky because it is in time hours/minutes/seconds, not the full year/month/day datetime, and `date2num` needs a full datetime. The trick here is we will use the original full date and time in the csv, convert it into a matplotlib timestamp and then subtract the "date" part we just calculated - so the remaining values are hours in matplotlib timestamps.

```
# Now we need to make the time (hours/minutes/second) into matplotlib timestamps too
# However matplotlib timestamps only works with full datetime timestamps(not just hours)
# Get the full datetime timestamps
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').to_numpy()

# Make a datetime object like previously
date_and_time_dt = np.array([datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in dates])

# Make them into matplotlib timestamps
date_and_time_timestamp = mdates.date2num(date_and_time_dt)

# Take out the 'year/month/day' part so we can keep the 'hour/minute/second' part
# Now we have the hour information in matplotlib timestamps
time_timestamp = date_and_time_timestamp - date_timestamp
```

So in the process of calculating the x values into matplotlib timestamps we have solved issue #1: now both x and y values are timestamps so we can do math with them, and issue #2: both x and y values are in matplotlib timestamps so they have the same units.

We can now calculate `r`:

```
# Convert the cartesian x and y coordinates into polar coordinates
r = np.sqrt(time_timestamp ** 2 + date_timestamp ** 2)
```

For `theta`, the angle, you can think of an angle as a fraction or percentage of a circle. A similar thought process can be applied to calculating `theta` here:

```
# We need the percentages of 24 hours for theta
# Calculate what one day is in matplotlib timestamps
delta_one_day_plt = mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 2)) - mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 1))
# Divide each hour/minute/second by the max amount in a day, and transform it into radians with 2 * PI
theta = (time_timestamp / delta_one_day_plt) * 2 * np.pi
```

Now that we have `r` and `theta`, we can finally plot the polar plot, following suggestions from the SO post [How to Plot Time Stamps HH:MM on Python Matplotlib "Clock" Polar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418087/how-to-plot-time-stamps-hhmm-on-python-matplotlib-clock-polar-plot):

```
# Initiate polar figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, layout='tight')
ax.scatter(theta, r, alpha=0.3)

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Place Zero at Top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2)
# Set the circumference ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
# Set the label names
ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 1)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
ax.set_xlabel('Date [Y/m/d] & Time [HH]')
# Set y lim so that it focuses on the dates in 2016
ax.set_ylim([mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 1)), mdates.date2num(datetime(2017, 1, 1))])
# Set y ticks so that it is in that 'gap' in the data and doesn't cover the points
ax.set_rlabel_position(140)
# Format y-axis for dates
y_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_fmt)

fig.suptitle('Tweet timeline')

plt.show()
```

[image: fig_polar]

As a sanity check, both graphs have a gap between the hours of 6 and 10, and a gap around September- October.

Hope this helps, matplotlib has a nice [Polar plot example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html). I have to admit this was a challenging problem and I enjoyed finding an answer, thanks for the question. Cheers!

Here is a copy of the full script just in case:

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


df_csv = pd.read_csv('data-tweets.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=['created'])
# For some reason, the data is not in utf-8 so it needs encoding ISO-8859-1
print(f'Available columns: {df_csv.columns.values}')

# Filter for 2016 as an example
df = df_csv[(df_csv['created'] >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00') & (df_csv['created'] <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00')]
# Reset index with the 2016 data
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Extract year/month/day to plot as y-axis
date = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d').to_numpy()
# Extract hour:minute:second to plot as x-axis
time = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').to_numpy()

# Time and date are currently strings, we need them to be datetime (dt) objects so matplotlib can understand
date_dt = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in date]
time_dt = [datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in time]

# Initiate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), layout='tight')
ax.plot(time_dt, date_dt, 'o')

# Format date/time for both x and y axes
x_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_fmt)
y_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_fmt)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

# Label axes
ax.set_xlabel('Time [HH:MM:SS]')
ax.set_ylabel('Date [Y/m/d]')
fig.suptitle('Tweet timeline')

plt.show()


# We need date and time to be timestamps (i.e. a number, not a datetime object) so we can operate with them
# Chose directly to do matplotlib timestamps as we can later format the axes like we did before
date_timestamp = mdates.date2num(date_dt)

# Now we need to make the time (hours/minutes/second) into matplotlib timestamps too
# However matplotlib timestamps only works with full datetime timestamps(not just hours)
# Get the full datetime timestamps
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['created']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').to_numpy()
# Make a datetime object like previously
date_and_time_dt = np.array([datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for x in dates])
# Make them into matplotlib timestamps
date_and_time_timestamp = mdates.date2num(date_and_time_dt)

# Take out the 'year/month/day' part so we can keep the 'hour/minute/second' part
# Now we have the hour information in matplotlib timestamps
time_timestamp = date_and_time_timestamp - date_timestamp

# Convert the cartesian x and y coordinates into polar coordinates
r = np.sqrt(time_timestamp ** 2 + date_timestamp ** 2)
# We need the percentages of 24 hours for theta
# Calculate what one day is in matplotlib timestamps
delta_one_day_plt = mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 2)) - mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 1))
# Divide each hour/minute/second by the max amount in a day, and transform it into radians with 2 * PI
theta = (time_timestamp / delta_one_day_plt) * 2 * np.pi

# Initiate polar figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, layout='tight')
ax.scatter(theta, r, alpha=0.3)

# Make the labels go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Place Zero at Top
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2)
# Set the circumference ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
# Set the label names
ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 1)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
ax.set_xlabel('Date [Y/m/d] & Time [HH]')
# Set y lim so that it focuses on the dates in 2016
ax.set_ylim([mdates.date2num(datetime(2016, 1, 1)), mdates.date2num(datetime(2017, 1, 1))])
# Set y ticks so that it is in that 'gap' in the data and doesn't cover the points
ax.set_rlabel_position(140)
# Format y-axis for dates
y_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_fmt)

fig.suptitle('Tweet timeline')

plt.show()
```